# Chomsky's Syntactic Structures: Why is {a^n b^n : n ∈ ℕ} not a finite state language?

Tags: syntax, grammar, theoretical-linguistics, chomsky

In (10) (i) of Chomsky's *Syntactic Strucures* (1957), the set of sentences of a specific language is defined as

> *ab, aabb, aaabbb, ...,* and in general, all sentences consisting of
>   *n* occurrences of *a* followed by *n* occurrences of *b* and only these

Chomsky then states that the non-finite-state nature of this language can be easily shown.

I don't see how, considering that he allows his finite state grammars to contain closed loops. [Ian Robinson doesn't understand it either and his is the only text I found addressing this.](https://books.google.at/books?id=05tuIekzBuIC&lpg=PA23&ots=C6bKHVocsP&dq=ian%20robinson%20finite%20state%20grammar&hl=de&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q=ian%20robinson%20finite%20state%20grammar&f=false)

What am I missing? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The point is that that *n = n*, i.e. you need to make sure not only that you have several occurences of *a*'s and *b*'s (which is easily achieved by loops), but that the number of *a*s and the number of *b*s be the same. This is a problem that can not be decided by FS automata. Most proofs demonstrating this make use of the [pumping lemma for regular langauges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). Another possibility is the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

Comment: If you google for *a^n b^n not regular* or something, you'll find lots of explanations.

Comment: @lemontree Thank you! I'll look into that!

Comment: Also keep in mind that this holds only for *{a^n b^n : n∈ℕ}*, i.e. words with *any such n*, i.e. the language *{ε, ab, aabb, aaabbb, ...}*. Things look differently for *arbitrary, but fixed n*, e.g. *{a^n b^n : n = 3} = {a^3 b^3} = {aaabbb}*, or *{a^n b^n : n ∈ {0,1,2}} = {ε, ab, aabb}*. These languages are indeed FS, because you can simply write down all of their words. This is not possible for the set ℕ (which is infinite).

Comment: Just read a bit of the chapter you linked to and I'm not quite sure whether he wants to make a point (if so, I don't get what it is that he wants to say) or whether he actually doesn't understand the problem. That diagram with the loop (n) thing he drew is nice, but simply not an FSA, because there is no such thing as loop counters in FSAs (or he has a non-standard model of FSAs, but in that case he can't use this as an argument against Chomsky's correct assertion which makes use of standard FSAs). The machine would do the job, but it would not be a FSA and is thus pointless to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: in a proper finite-state language, you only need finite memory to determine whether an arbitrary pattern is valid or not. This language requires you to remember how many `a`s have been encountered, and that number is unbounded.**

Long version:

There is a very nice intuitive "proof" that this is not a finite-state language, which can be made rigorous through some additional work. In true mathematical fashion, this additional work is left as an exercise for the reader.

Let us say `{a^n b^n : n ∈ ℕ}` is a finite state language. This means that we can construct a finite state machine which takes in a series of characters as input, and outputs `TRUE` if that series of characters matches your language, or `FALSE` if it does not. So if we feed the finite state machine `ab` it will say `TRUE`; if we feed it `aaabbb` it will say `TRUE`; if we feed it `aaabb` it will say `FALSE`.

To match this language, our finite state machine needs to remember how many `a`s it has seen, in order to make sure the number of `b`s is the same. And the only way a finite state machine can remember anything is through its state. So the machine needs a state for "I have seen one `a` so far", another state for "I have seen two `a`s so far", and so on.

But you're allowing *any natural number* of `a`s. This would require the machine to have no fewer states than there are natural numbers, in order for it to remember accurately how many `a`s it's seen.

Since there are an infinite quantity of natural numbers, we need an infinite quantity of states. But this contradicts the definition of a *finite* state machine.

So we have a contradiction. There cannot be such a finite state machine, and thus your language is not a finite state language.

Comment: Alternate and more rigorous proof: look at [the pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). If you divide a string in your language into three parts, there are two possible cases. If the middle part contains only `a`s or only `b`s, then repeating that middle part while keeping the beginning and end the same will increase the quantity of one letter but not the other. If the middle part contains both `a`s and `b`s, then repeating it will place an `a` after a `b`. Either way, the result is not a valid string in your language. No pumping, so not finite state.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a somewhat detailed, yet informal discussion of this topic in Chapter 5 of Isac and Reiss 2008/2013 *I-Language: An Introduction to Linguistics as Cogntive Science*. (I am one of the authors.)

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.